# Prove if $A$ has full column rank, then $A+E$ is also has full column rank if $\|E\|_2\leq \frac{1}{\|A^{\dagger}\|_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Prove if $A\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$ has full column rank, then $A+E$ is also has full column rank if $\|E\|_2\leq  \frac{1}{\|A^{\dagger}\|_2},$ where $A^{\dagger}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T.$

Comment: The custom of this site is that you give some context. What have you tried, where do you get stuck? That sort of thing.

Comment: $m\ge n{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: $A$ has full column rank implying that $m\geq n.$

Answer (score 1):

The key point of this proof is to notice that the condition on the norm restricts the maximum singular value of $E$.
For the details, first apply SVD to matrix $A$:
$$ A = U\left[
\begin{array}
    & \Sigma \\
    0
\end{array}
\right]V^{H} $$
, where $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are unitary matrices and the diagonal elements of $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive because $A$ has full rank in columns, i.e. $\sigma_i > 0$ for $\forall i\in\{1, 2 ,\cdots, n\}$.

Easy to verify that $A^{+} = V[\Sigma^{-1}, 0]U^{H}$, and thus $\|A^{+}\|_2 = (\min_{i}{\sigma_i})^{-1}$.
So the condition is equivalent to
$$ \|E\|_2 = \max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}{\frac{\|Ex\|_2}{\|x\|_2}}\le (\|A^{+}\|_2)^{-1} = \min_{i}{\sigma_i}$$
Note that $V$ is unitary so the columns of $V$ spans the space $R^{n}$, which means that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $x = V\lambda$.
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{$A + E$ has full column rank} & \iff \text{$(A + E)x \neq 0$ for any nonzero $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$} \\
        & \iff \text{$(A + E)V\lambda \neq 0$ for any nonzero $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Suppose $(A+E)V\lambda = 0$ for some nonzero $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ (A+E)V\lambda = A\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_iv_i\right) + Ex = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i\sigma_i u_i + Ex = 0$$
where $u_i\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are column vectors of $U$ and $V$.
Now we have to find a contradiction to show that this is impossible.
Consider the norm of both sides:
$$ \|Ex\|_2^2 = \|\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i\sigma_i u_i\|_2^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\sigma_i^2$$
On the other hand, $\|Ex\|_2 \le \|E\|_2\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_2^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\lambda_i^2}$, so naturally we get
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\sigma_i^2 = \|Ex\|_2^2 \le \|E\|_2^2\|x\|_2^2 = \left(\min_j{\sigma_j^2}\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\lambda_i^2}\right) \le \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\sigma_i^2 $$
The equality is achieved if and only if $\sigma_i = \sigma, \forall i$, i.e. all the singular values of $A$ are the same, say the identity matrix.
In fact, if $A = I$ and $E = -I$, which satisfies the given condition, yields $A + E = 0$ that is not full rank.
As long as the singular values of $A$ is not identical, the equality in the above inequality can never be achieved, i.e.
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\sigma_i^2 \le \left(\min_j{\sigma_j^2}\right)\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\lambda_i^2}\right) < \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lambda_i^2\sigma_i^2 $$
So here we get the contradiction, and thus prove that $A+E$ has full column rank.

So in conclusion, $A+E$ has full column rank as long as singular values of $A$ are not identical.
Also note that if you change your condition to $\|E\|_2 < (\|A^{+}\|_2)^{-1}$ then $A+E$ always has full column rank no matter what the singular values are.

Comment: Do you suppose that $A+E$ has full column rank and get the inequality holds?

Comment: @Neo I am supposing $(A+E)V\lambda = 0$ for some nonzero $\lambda$ and trying to find a contradiction. If the equality can never be achieved, then it means $(A+E)V\lambda \neq 0$ for any $\lambda \neq 0$ and this proves that $A+E$ has full column rank. I have updated the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the intended condition was $\|E\| \color{red}< 1/\|A^\dagger\|$. It's easy to see that $\|E\| \leq 1/\|A^\dagger\|$ is insufficient by taking $A = 1$ and $E = -1$.

Here's a quick proof. Note that if $A^\dagger(A + E)$ has is invertible (i.e. has full rank), then $A + E$ must have full column rank. On the other hand,
$$
A^\dagger(A + E) = I + A^\dagger E.
$$
Now, if $\|E\|_2 < \|A^\dagger\|^{-1}$, then $\|A^\dagger E\|_2 \leq \|A^\dagger\|_2\cdot \|E\|_2 < 1$. However, it generally holds that if $\|M\|_2 < 1$, then $I + M$ must be invertible (as can be seen using the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series), for example). So, taking $M = A^\dagger E$, we see that $A^\dagger(A + E) = I + M$ is indeed invertible, which means that $A + E$ must have full column rank, which was what we wanted.